# Javascript replace regex any character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace something like '?order=height' and I know it can be easily done like this:

```
data = 'height'

x = '?order=' + data

x.replace('?order=' + data, '')
```

But the problem is that question mark can sometimes be ampersand.. What I really wish to do is make blank whether the first character is ampersand or question mark so basically whether

```
?order=height
&order=height
```

can be made a blank string

Comment: @GOTO0, I updated my question and forgot to mention that the height is supposed to be a variable that is being concatenated

Comment: If your string looks like `http://example.com?order=1&foo=2`, when your remove `?order=1` you are left with `http://example.com&foo=2`, which is not a valid URL (there should be a "?" after "com", not a "&"). Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: Yes I am sure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you may do it. Create a `RegExp` object with

```
"[&?]order=" + match
```

and replace with "" using `String.prototype.replace`

```js
function replace(match, str) {
   regex = new RegExp("[&?]order=" + match,"g")
  return str.replace(regex, "")
}

console.log(replace("height", "Yo &order=height Yo"))
console.log(replace("weight", "Yo ?order=weight Yo"))
console.log(replace("age", "Yo ?order=age Yo"))
```

Comment: what if the value 'height' is supposed to be a variable?

Comment: then you may change it as `   regex = /[&?]order=[^ \t]+/g`

Comment: Update my question, I meant something else

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @Sarathp, I actually want to concatenate my variable inside your regex variable, is that possible?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada You can check the answer

Comment: Your answer is perfect!

Comment: console.log(replace("height", "?order=435&test=324"))

Comment: @AlexandrMalyita this has to be  `console.log(replace("435", "?order=435&test=324"))`

Answer (score 3):

```
x.replace(/[&?]order=height/, '')
```

If data is string variable

```
x.replace(/[&?]order=([^&=]+)/, '')
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you still need to escape it inside character group? I newer escape `[.]` and it matches `.` and not any char

Comment: what if the value 'height' is supposed to be a variable?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada Please give an example

Comment: Update my question

Comment: data is integer or string ?

Comment: @AlexandrMalyita, string

Answer (score 2):

Use regex for that `.replace(/[?&]order=height/, '')`

`[?&]` means any character from this list.

`/` is start and end delimiter.

Please note that pattern is not enclosed as string with `'` or `"`.

Comment: what if the value 'height' is supposed to be a variable?

Comment: Update my question